# Applying One hot encoding on a particular column of a dataset but result was not as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset with five columns.

Dataset:

```
Country       Population    Tourism    Mean_Age    Employed
Afghanistan  37172386       14000      17.3        Fulltime
Albania      2866376        5340000    36.2        Parttime
```

There are almost 1000 data like this where `Employed` is a categorical column. I want to represent the `Employed` column as a numerical column using **one hot encoding**.

My code is

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
Employed_Status = data["Employed"]
encoder = OneHotEncoder()
encoder.fit(Employed_Status.values.reshape(-1, 1))
encoder.transform(Employed_Status.head().values.reshape(-1, 1)).todense()
```

Here `data` is the name of my data frame.

When I try to see the dataset after executing above lines I got the previous data set.

However, I thought I would get something like that

```
Country       Population    Tourism    Mean_Age    Employed
Afghanistan  37172386       14000      17.3        1
Albania      2866376        5340000    36.2        0
```

As I have applied one hot encoding on `Employed` column.

Can any one tell me why I got the same result and not the desired one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not saving the output.

```
out = encoder.transform(...).todense()

data['employed'] = out
```

It may take some wrangling to get the datasets to go together. I have found `pd.concat(numerical_in, categorical_encoded_in, axis=1)` is needed in the past but you might simply find it works once you save the dense output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
data['Employed'] = data['Employed'].replace('Fulltime',1).replace('Parttime',0)
```